# Redis and Google Cloud Functions

Tags: redis, google-cloud-functions, ioredis

I'm using `ioredis` to `set` values to a redis enterprise instance.

1. How do I close the connection after a few seconds to reduce the number of clients created ?
2. Do I need to close the connection at all ?
3. Does every invocation spawn a redis client ?
4. Do I need a VPC connector ?
5. How do I ensure the fucntion runs on the same `ip:port` to prevent creation of other instances

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

import Redis = require("ioredis");
const redis = new Redis("redis://default:jMSNpTm3JXs1@redis-15360.c228.us-central1-1.gce.cloud.redislabs.com:15360");

export const SaveRecord = functions.https.onCall(async (data,context)=>{
  const {record,recordID} = data;
  try{
    var result =  await redis.multi().set(recordID, record).expire(recordID,3600).exec();
    return result;
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e);
    return "error";
  }
})
```

Comment: Where is hosted your redis instance? On Google Cloud? In Memorystore? Elsewhere?

Comment: Redis Enterprise Cloud

Comment: Did you have installed it from the marketplace? Are you seeing the deployed infrastructure in your project?

Comment: No... Calling it upon initialization

Comment: I didn't catch you. How have you initialized your Redis cloud instance? where is it hosted?

Comment: I'm using `redislabs` [Redis Enterprise Cloud](https://app.redislabs.com/) on GCP Cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never deployed Redis Cloud Enterprise on my project but I can already provide these answers

1,2,3. You don't need to close the connection at every connexion. In your code, you start (line 4) a connexion to your Redis and you store it in global variable (in the global scope, not in function body).

That means, when to Cloud Functions instance start, it call all the global code (your first 4 lines, and then call your functions. the `redis` variable is kept between Cloud Functions invocation.

However, you need to check the redis Cloud default connexion timeout and be able to perform a reconnect in case of closed connexion (exception handling in your code).

About connexion to close, it also depends on the Redis Cloud configuration: is the idle connexion are automatically closed? If not, it will be difficult. Try to close the idle connexion by Redis server configuration after 1 hour of idle activity or less. (Cloud Functions instances are usually offloaded after 30 minutes of inactivity, without any Google Cloud commitment).

4. Yes; If you check the IP registered on your URL (for example `nelookup redis-15360.c228.us-central1-1.gce.cloud.redislabs.com`), you will find a URL in 172.26.x.x. It's a RFC 1918 private IP. The DNS resolution is external (ask redislab URL the IP of the server), but the targeted server is internal to your project. You can route only internal traffic.
5. The Cloud Functions service create and destroy instances according to the HTTP traffics. You can't prevent the creation or the destruction of instances, it's serverless. Similarly, you doesn't have an IP/PORT associated to your Cloud Functions instance, it's serverless. If you want to have only 1 Cloud Functions instance, you can set the max instance to 1. But, Be careful, Cloud functions can handle only 1 request at a time on a same instance. With a max instance to 1, is you have 2 concurrent requests, 1 will be processed, the other will wait, and after 10 seconds a 417 HTTP error will be returned.

Comment: Thank You for your insight.  I moved the initialization to  the inside of the function. Hope it wont change the transactions

Comment: If you change that, that means you will "pay" the initialisation duration on each request, instead of once per instance created. It should be easier to manage, but not the most efficient!